# Как реализовать погоду на 5 дней android java

Tags: java, android

````
        DownloadJSON downloadJSON = new DownloadJSON();
        try {
            String result = "abc";
            result = downloadJSON.execute(url).get();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject main = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main");
            String temp = main.getString("temp");
            String feel_like = main.getString("feels_like");
            String humidity = main.getString("humidity");
            String preassure = main.getString("pressure");
            String wind = jsonObject.getJSONObject("wind").getString("speed");
            String time = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getString("description");
            txtCity.setText(City);
            txtDate.setText(time);
            txtValueTemp.setText(temp +"°");
            txtValueHumidy.setText(humidity+"%");
            txtValueFeelLike.setText(feel_like+"°");
            txtValuePressure.setText(preassure+"hPa");
            txtValueWind.setText(wind+" м/с");
            String nameIcon = "10d";
            nameIcon = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getString("icon");
            String urlIcon = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+nameIcon+"@2x.png";
            DownloadIcon downloadIcon = new DownloadIcon();
            Bitmap bitmap = downloadIcon.execute(urlIcon).get();
            Status_weather_icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }```
Сделал получение текущей, как по такому принципу, простому сделать на 5 дней, а то в интернете есть примеры но я их, не понимаю.
````

Comment: Или как получить JSON первый день по этой ссылке: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2&units=metric&lang=ru&appid=f0d8819db15df1b47132ed74da2a3770

Comment: https://openweathermap.org/forecast16